# Passing data in a "permanent" room database from a manifest declared broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I'm very new to android development and am using kotlin since I don't know java and have been told it's better to use kotlin for android dev. I have a project where I need to constantly intercept SMS, register them and show them on an UI.

To test receiving SMS, I used a manifest registered broadcast receiver. The lucky thing is, this seems to work without needing to launch the app.
The downside is that I can't find a way to save anything that I intercept other than with a room database, which would, I guess, be only accessible from the BroadcastReceiver, or with my open app's context. But I need for the data to be persistent and available to the rest of my app, and at the same time I need it to be registered while only my broadcastreceiver is working. I thought of doing some kind of third service with workmanager, but through research, I figured out (I think ?) it would be impossible due to the limitations imposed on the duration of this kind of task.
I also read about contentproviders but I don't know if those would be accessible when my app isn't started. I don't even know if it would be correct to use that to transmit data between what I assume are two components of the same app. I thought about using files, but for me that means abandoning the guidelines I found about using Room (I am severely lacking time), as well as flow which is super useful.

What should I do ? Here is my base project, in which nothing too interesting is happening (yet) :
MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.smssender

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Telephony
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var phoneEdt: EditText
    lateinit var phoneSetEdt: EditText
    lateinit var messageEdt: EditText
    lateinit var sendMsgBtn: Button
    lateinit var setPhoneBtn: Button
    lateinit var currentPhone: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_MMS)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
                android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
                android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_MMS,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE), 111)
        }
        else
            receiveMsg()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode==111 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            receiveMsg()
    }

    private fun receiveMsg() { //cette fonction lance l'écouteur de SMS et les autres fonctionnalités et est invoquée seulement si les permissions sont toutes accordées.
        // PARTIE RECEPTION :
        val test = MyReceiver()

        phoneEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtPhone)
        phoneSetEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtPhoneSet)
        messageEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtMessage)
        sendMsgBtn = findViewById(R.id.idBtnSendMessage)
        setPhoneBtn = findViewById(R.id.idBtnSetRaspPhone)
        currentPhone = findViewById(R.id.idTextCurrentPhone)


        sendMsgBtn.setOnClickListener {


            // variables for phone and message
            val phoneNumber = phoneEdt.text.toString()
            val message = messageEdt.text.toString()

            try {

                // on below line we are initializing sms manager.
                //as after android 10 the getDefault function no longer works
                //so we have to check that if our android version is greater
                //than or equal toandroid version 6.0 i.e SDK 23
                val smsManager:SmsManager
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                    //if SDK is greater that or equal to 23 then
                    //this is how we will initialize the SmsManager
                    smsManager = applicationContext.getSystemService<SmsManager>(SmsManager::class.java)
                }
                else{
                    //if user's SDK is less than 23 then
                    //SmsManager will be initialized like this
                    smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
                }

                // on below line we are sending text message.
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null)

                // on below line we are displaying a toast message for message send,
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            } catch (e: Exception) {

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please enter all the data.."+e.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
        }
        setPhoneBtn.setOnClickListener {// tout ça ne peut marcher que si on lance le broadcast receiver sur un service ou si on l'attache à mainactivity, ce qui limite les possibilités d'exécution
            val phoneNumToSet = phoneSetEdt.text.toString()
            if(phoneNumToSet.isNotEmpty()) {
                val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, MyReceiver::class.java)
                i.action = "CHANGE_PHONE_NUM"
                i.putExtra("setPhone", phoneNumToSet)
                sendBroadcast(i)
                currentPhone.text = phoneNumToSet
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyReceiver.kt

```
package com.example.smssender

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.Intent.getIntent
import android.content.Intent.getIntentOld
import android.os.Build
import android.provider.Telephony
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.MainScope

class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() { // attention !!! : chaque broadcast reçu créera une nouvelle instance de cette classe. Les attributs de celle-ci ne seront donc pas conservés. (On pourrait peut-être les stocker dans le serveur qui fait tourner)
    var raspNum: String = "0781054734" // à rendre modifiable dans les paramètres de l'interface principale et a rendre persistant
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (p1 != null) {
                if(p1.action == "CHANGE_PHONE_NUM") {
                    raspNum = p1.getStringExtra("setPhone").toString()
                    Toast.makeText(p0, "the deed is done, my master... the new number is $raspNum", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    for(sms in Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(p1)){
                        if(sms.displayOriginatingAddress == raspNum) { // pour que la chaine d'envoi de données ne soit pas accessible à des joe le rigolo
                            Toast.makeText(p0, sms.displayMessageBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            //abortBroadcast() //apparemment on ne peut plus empêcher le broadcast sans être l'app de SMS par défaut (voir liens kotlin 11)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- on below line we are adding sms permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" /> <!-- permet de lire des SMS reçus alors que l'app est allumée -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SMSSender"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="CHANGE_PHONE_NUM"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```